# What are the minimum and maximum valid dates in Salesforce?

Tags: date, datetime, format

What are the minimum and maximum valid dates in Salesforce?

What is the valid date range in Apex, SOQL or SOAP API?

It is hard to find anything in the documentation

Comment: Just curious: why would you need this?

Comment: To be honest, I met a lot of issues importing data from external systems where building date was older then 1700... So it is useful to know

Comment: I have been working on Salesforce Platform for 5 years and I have never thought about this. However, our client company was acquired by one of the biggest and oldest IT company and now we have to integrate their data into client Salesforce organization and data which comes has some strange date values like '99991231',  '00010101',  '99999999'  0001,01,01 0059,01,01 etc.

Answer (score 9):

Initially I have found an answer [here](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000giqGAAQ), but the link provided in that answer, was broken.

Finally found a corresponding valid link [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm?search_text=date%20format)

> **Minimum and Maximum Dates**
>
> Only dates within a certain range are
>   valid. The earliest valid date is 1700-01-01T00:00:00Z GMT, or just
>   after midnight on January 1, 1700. The latest valid date is
>   4000-12-31T00:00:00Z GMT, or just after midnight on December 31, 4000.
>   These values are offset by your time zone. For example, in the Pacific
>   time zone, the earliest valid date is 1699-12-31T16:00:00, or 4:00 PM
>   on December 31, 1699.

Comment: I just wonder what would happen after this 4000-12-31T00:00:00Z GMT. Hope the humans still use the Salesforce.

Comment: @ArnoldJr. I know I personally can't wait for APIv5987.0 :p